# AWS Boto3 S3: I accidentally renamed a set of files as empty string. They're gone right?

Tags: python-3.x, string, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

To "rename" some files I copied them with a new name and then deleted the originals. In creating the new name I meant to do this:

```
new_key_path = '.'.join(key_path.split('.')[0:3])
```

But I did this

```
new_key_path = '.'.join(str.split('.')[0:3])
```

`key_path` vs `str`. The former is a valid variable (path to file), the latter was apparently not `None`, but an empty string. So it didn't error out. The result of this was that all iterations set `new_key_path` to `.`. The rest of the logic was such that I was essentially copying to the "root" of the s3 bucket...

Anyway, I can get the data back elsewhere but just want to validate that I indeed messed up in this specific way. I don't see it anywhere else in the bucket. Thanks

EDIT: adding the example renaming code. [This is out of the box with Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/s3.html#S3.MultipartUploadPart.copy_from).

```
self.s3_resource.Object(self._bucket_name, new_key_path).copy_from(CopySource=copy_src)
self.s3_resource.Object(self._bucket_name, key_path).delete()
```

Comment: Is the object versioning turned on for this bucket?

Comment: How did you "copy them with a new name"? Amazon S3 does not have a 'rename' command. Did you use the AWS CLI? Or can you show us some code? What do you see if you run `aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKETNAME`?

Comment: @jellycsc, no I checked that first thing but versioning was off.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, right there is no re-name mechanism. I copied the files with a new name, and deleted the originals as a work-around. I edited the question with example code.

Comment: Ok, then they are non-recoverable.

Comment: It sounds like each object was successively copied to the same name. The last file to be copied might still be available under that name, but not the earlier ones. D'oh!